# How can I fix Xcode 4.6 LLVM compiler error?

Tags: ios, wordpress, clang, xcode4.6

I've just checked out a copy of WordPress for iOS from the Subversion Repository: http://iphone.svn.wordpress.org/trunk/

However trying to compile and run it on the 5.1 or 6.1 simulator gives me a weird error I've never seen before:

*clang: error: no such file or directory: '/private/tmp/WordPress.build/WordPressComApiCredentials.m'
clang: error: no input files
Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1*

I have already tired to clean the project and reset the simulator but that didn't help either. From other posts I understand that something about "clang" is set in the code - but I don't know what it is.

Could someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you check out the source into your `/tmp` or `/private/tmp` directory? Files can sometimes disappear from there without warning - try checking it out elsewhere and building it again.

Comment: Hi Tim, no I've checked it out into my Mac's user directory. In fact I tried checking out the 3.4 tag too but it didn't make a difference.